How can I set up Delphi/RAD Studio IDE in a Container? Is this possible?
I noticed the Lazarus IDE and VSCode can be put into Docker Containers as devcontainers, so that you can develop and compile software inside that container. I have no experience with Docker, and I cannot seem to find any data on the internet on how to install/place the RAD Studio IDE into a container. So, I was hoping that someone here on SO could assist?
Is it indeed possible to install/setup the RAD Studio (not RAD Server) IDE into a container?

In general it's hard and platform-specific to run GUI applications in a container, and you won't have access to shared OS settings or the user's home directory or other files in most cases.  I'd just install the IDE and other development tools you need on your host system.

Hi David! I am unable to install anything on my host machine at the moment, which is why I was hoping to be able to put together a RAD Studio dev-container

While there have been attempts to install the compiler in a Docker container, I am not aware of any way to do that for the whole IDE.

There are blog posts by Embarcadero for how to get Delphi-compiled Linux apps and RADServer/PAServer installed in Docker containers. But not the IDE/compiler itself. You should file a feature request.

Neither IDE can be put into a Docker container. Other non-GUI parts can similar to what PAServer provides for Delphi but with some additional / similar features.  Ex: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers

@Brian The IDE itself, no. But it may be nice if Embarcadero provided (or made possible to make) containers for the command-line compilers and libs, at least.

Docker runs on Linux kernel. Windows version of docker is based on WSL2, basically a VM with Linux. In order to run windows application inside docker container, it should contain a full blown VM with Windows. If you will try to run such container in Windows, you will basically run your app in Windows VM that runs in Linux VM, that runs on Windows. Such solution will be very slow and bugprone.
If you want to run RAD Studio on a computer where you do not have rights to install it, the best option will be to setup a VM with RAD Studio in the cloud (like MS Azure, Amazon AWS) or on your home hardware. Than connect to it via some sort of VPN and use Remote Desktop Connection. On a good internet, experience will be close to running VM localy.

It is possible and you may find some unofficial docker images on hub.docker.com. Basically, you need to put your IDE files and configs into a windows container:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
SHELL ["powershell"]
...

And set all necessary environment variables:
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('BDS', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    $bdsBin = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin'; \
    $bdsBin64 = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin64'; \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('BDSBIN', $bdsBin, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('BDSCOMMONDIR', 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('BDSINCLUDE', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\include', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('BDSLIB', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\lib', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    $frameworkDir = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'; \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FrameworkDir', $frameworkDir, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FrameworkVersion', 'v4.5', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('LANGDIR', 'EN', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + ';' + $frameworkDir + ';' + $bdsBin + ';' + $bdsBin64), [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + ';' + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','User');

then you can compile your projects like this:
docker run -v C:\host_dir:C:\build\app your_docker_image msbuild /t:build C:\build\app\YourApp.dproj

